# How to add mask control points in compositor masks?

Tags: compositing-nodes, masking

I need to mask the outer part of the box, yet `CTRL + Left Mouse Button` doesn't add any controlpoints in the image editor. The tutorials I've found are useless since they point to V. 2.79 where masks seem to be a part of UV editor.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if mask display is enabled. It seems to be disabled in default render view.

[image]